# Multiline heading in scrreprt and figure placement

Tags: floats, pdftex, header-footer, koma-script

I am trying to use a template built with `scrreprt` and `scrpage2`, which has a multiline heading. While the `headheight` option doesn't seem to have any effect, defining `topskip` works quite well, at least for text (see page two in result below). However, when a figure is placed at the top of the page, it is put right over the lower parts of the heading, even though enough space is reserved in the textarea. How can this be made to work?

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, headings=small,
    paper=a4,
    pagesize,
    headinclude=true,
    headheight=50mm,   % doesn't seem to have any effect
    footinclude=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\areaset[current]{165mm}{276mm}
\setlength{\topskip}{20mm}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\my@headwidth}
\setlength{\my@headwidth}{173mm}
\setheadwidth[-2.05mm]{\my@headwidth}

\clearscrheadfoot
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\my@head}{%
    \noindent
    {\large
        \hspace{2.05mm}\raisebox{3mm}{My Organization}
    }
    \\[9mm]
    \noindent
    {further\hfill header\hfill information}
}
\newcommand{\my@page }{Page \thepage{}}
\ihead[\my@head]{\my@head}
\ofoot[\my@page]{\my@page}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
  % there is enough space for the figure, but it doesn't seem to care about
  % the topskip
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{demo}
    \caption{Demo}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Since KOMA-Script version 3.22 option `areasetadvanced` is explained in the KOMA-Script documentation. If this option is set, option `headinclude` and `footinclude` are taken into account by `\areaset`. Then there is no need to use `geometry` in the example.

```
\documentclass[
  headings=small,
  headlines=5,
  headinclude,
  footinclude,
  areasetadvanced% <- added
]{scrreprt}

\areaset[current]{165mm}{276mm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[
  headwidth=173mm:-2.05mm,
  manualmark
]
{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}

\ihead*{%
    {\large
      \hspace{2.05mm}\raisebox{3mm}{My Organization}
    }\\[9mm]
    further\hfill header\hfill information
}

\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page\ \thepage}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{demo}
    \caption{Demo}
  \end{figure}
  \the\textheight
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Original answer**

It seems that `\areaset` does not pay attention to the option `headheight` during its recalculation of the page layout.

If you need a special layout, it is better to use package `geometry`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=small,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[
  top=7mm,
  bottom=14mm,
  headheight=5\baselineskip,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  heightrounded,
  textwidth=165mm,
  %showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[
  headwidth=173mm:-2.05mm,
  manualmark
]
{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}

\ihead*{%
    {\large
      \hspace{2.05mm}\raisebox{3mm}{My Organization}
    }\\[9mm]
    further\hfill header\hfill information
}

\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page\ \thepage}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{demo}
    \caption{Demo}
  \end{figure}
  \the\textheight
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

I have switched from the outdated package `scrpage2` to `scrlayer-scrpage`. The options pagesize (since version 3.17), `11pt`, `paper=a4` are default.

Comment: Additional note: Option `areasetadvanced` was [first mentioned for KOMA-Script release 3.11](https://komascript.de/release3.11) in 2012.